# How can i upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 final from 14.04 Beta correctly?

Tags: upgrade, 14.04

I tried to upgrade to 14.04 Final release from 14.04 Beta. I executed following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

My system updated packages after `dist-upgrade`. However after `do-release-upgrade` it gives the following output:

```
vijay@vijay-Inspiron-5520:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found
```

How to upgrade from beta correctly?

Comment: *You missed (at least) one important step.* Correct **three** (3) commands to *fully* update are: **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`**, followed by **`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do nothing.

Since you are already on Trusty beta and are using the Trusty section of the Ubuntu repos, you should (by now) already have the packages that are used for the official Trusty release.