# The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state

Tags: upgrade

When the stable version of Ubuntu 14.04 was released I tried to to upgrade without any results, so i did:

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

But when I was upgrading the files I went off without electricity and my laptop didn't have the battery.
Ok, I could fix it with an earlier state of ubuntu, but now I'm having problems in the option "Software Updater", for switching from developers version to stable version. When I click in Software updater it says it can run only "Partial Upgrade". See image:

[image]

Then I run a partial upgrade and just nothing happens. See this one:

[image]

Well, I reported the bug but I'm looking for a solution.

Then I tried again

```
sudo update-manager -d
```

and this was the result:

```
**Could not install the upgrades**

The upgrade has aborted. Your system could be in an unusable state. A recovery will run now (dpkg --configure -a)."

The output from shell is:

    [000:000] Cpu: 6.42.7, x2, 1600Mhz, 7686MB
    [000:000] Computer model: Not available
    [000:000] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
    [000:000] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
    [000:000] Using Gtk2 toolkit
    [000:002] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
    [000:002] No bp log location saved, using default.
    [000:003] Cpu: 6.42.7, x2, 1600Mhz, 7686MB
    [000:003] Computer model: Not available
    [000:003] Browser XEmbed support present: 1
    [000:003] Browser toolkit is Gtk2.
    [000:003] Using Gtk2 toolkit
    No bp log location saved, using default.
    [000:000] Cpu: 6.42.7, x2, 1600Mhz, 7686MB
    [000:000] Computer model: Not available
    [000:013] Warning(optionsfile.cc:47): Load: Could not open file, err=2
    [000:013] No bp log location saved, using default.
    [000:014] Cpu: 6.42.7, x2, 1600Mhz, 7686MB
    [000:014] Computer model: Not available
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then `sudo apt-get update`. Edit your question and include any errors you may encounter.

Comment: I fixed it. I think my question is duplicated because there is a similar question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/449385/how-can-i-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04-final-from-14-04-beta-correctly?rq=1 , so a did ´sudo apt-get dist-upgrade´ and now my computer now is up-to-date :) Thank u anyway